# Split/Identify a number at the end of a string, that doesn't have a fixed number of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of files, in folders that I want to rename. The format is:

```
lesson1
lesson2
.....
lesson11
lesson99
lesson100
lesson130
```

When I sort in Windows, the order is my string, so is not correct(example):

```
lesson1 
lesson100
```

I want to become (rename):

```
_001_lesson
_010_lesson
```

How do I catch/split the numbering part at the end from the string 'lesson' ?

also a more complex case when the string is not fixed(as lesson):

```
title abc1
title def2
title acr 3
```

Comment: What happens if you had something like: `lesson1_part5_2018` or similar?

Comment: I don't have that situation, only the lesson number at the end, but if your solution can cover other cases also, it is great

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort ?

Comment: You can extract numbers from a string using `''.join([i for i in l if i.isdigit()])` where l is the string. Combine this with a for loop to iterate through your names

Comment: @JonClements I will try natsort, even if my thought was to extract the number, and rename the file, not sorting

Comment: In those answers there's also examples of how to extract numbers from strings... once you've done that - you can rename the file if you want... In fact - Leopold's answered with just that :)

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is the following, using [python's re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```py
import re

def rename(old_name):
  # Run a Regex to find the ending number
  match = re.search('lesson(\d+)', old_name)

  # If that was a match (that should be necessary, but 
  # checking input is always a good idea)
  if match:
    # Retrieves the id and converts it to an integer
    id = int(match.group(1))

    # Gets the formatted name out
    return '_{:03d}_lesson'.format(id)

  return None
```

This is quite modular. You can change the regex next time you want to parse similar file names :).

Comment: I really need to get into `re`, it looks strong.

Comment: You could make this very modular Leopold - something like https://gist.github.com/puppystack/d9f4148ecfd0863a2972410e0835bbda ?

Answer (score 1):

For the fixed string, you can use the `split` method:

```
Number = "lesson123".split("lesson")[1] # "123"
Title  = "lesson123".split(Number)[0]   # "lesson"
```

For `_001_lesson` you can write something like this, assuming you need N extra zeros in front of the number.

```
New_name = "_" + N*"0" + "%d_%s" %(Number, Title)
```

For your other example, I understand you want to grab all the characters after "title"?

```
Number = "title acr 3".split("title")[1] # " acr 3"
Title = "title acr 3".split(Number)[0]   # "title"
```

If you are annoyed by those extra spaces you can remove them using `strip` or `replace`:

```
Clean_number = Number.strip(" ")
# or
Clean_number = Number.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: 'title acr', is just a placeholder, is not fixed particle, can be anything instead, and I want to get only the number

Comment: Only "3"? Then `text.strip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")` will do.